# I have used .htaccess for user validation but this validation also occur when I upload the images

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex admin-index.php
AuthName "Admin Control Panel"
AuthUserFile "/home/var/.htpasswds/public_html/admin/passwd"
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

I want to upload images feature not protected by .htaccess.

Comment: You can upload to a non-protect directory URI, or authenticate using PHP and not your .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

You basically have one simple option: move the script for uploading of a file to another directory which *isn't* protected by this `.htaccess` file. Alternatively, you could do authentication another way than with `.htaccess`, although this will take more time and effort.